# Ada - how to initialize a limited tagged type that contains File_Type members?

Tags: oop, inheritance, syntax, ada

In the following code Mix_Card_Reader inherits from Mix_IO_Device, the latter being an abstract tagged record.

Previously it contained one `Positive` and two `Stream_Access` members.  I'd like to alter the code so that it uses `File_Type` members instead.

The reason for that is that I want each instance of this type to be able to open and close its files as and when required, or not at all if need be.

The problem is that I cannot initialise this inheriting type because `File_Type` is a limited type.  How can I write my `Create_Mix_Card_Reader` function to allow this?

> .ads...

```
   type Mix_IO_Device is abstract tagged limited
      record
         Block_Size : Positive;
         Input_File : File_Type;
         Output_File : File_Type;
      end record;

   type Mix_Card_Reader is new Mix_IO_Device with null record;
```

> .adb...

```
   function Create_Mix_Card_Reader return Mix_IO_Device_Access is
      Ret : Mix_IO_Device_Access := new Mix_Card_Reader'(16, null, null);
   begin
      return Ret;
   end Create_Mix_Card_Reader;
```

GNAT is complaining that I cannot pass `null, null` into the pair of `File_Type` members because they are not compatible of course, the nulls are a left-over from when this used to have `Stream_Access` members.  It seems that I have to pass something in here but I don't want to have to prematurely open the files simply to placate the compiler.

What to do?

Edit:
I have a couple of obvious options:

- use `access File_Type` instead (but I still have to maintain the opening/closing of the files elsewhere).
- store all the File_Type objects in an array separately and just refer to them using Streams as before but this seems messy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function Create_Mix_Card_Reader return Mix_IO_Device_Access is
   Ret : Mix_IO_Device_Access := new Mix_Card_Reader'(
     16, Input_Type => <>, Ouptut_Type => <>);
begin
   return Ret;
end Create_Mix_Card_Reader;
```

The box notation is a placeholder for the default value. You need at least Ada 2005 to use it in aggregates and must not use positional notation, details are explained in the [Ada 2005 Rationale](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-4-4.html). You can shorten the two assignments to `others => <>` if you want.

Comment: Now that's neat!  I wouldn't have guessed that was possible.  I'm using 2012 thankfully.  Works like a charm and is a good deal easier to understand than my ugly hack.  Many thanks. +1

Answer (score 2):

You don’t really need to initialize the `File_Type` variables, since they start off initialized (but not opened).

I got the impression that you didn’t start off using an access type? Try this (not an answer to the question as posed, but may still be useful):

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
package Wossname is

   type Mix_IO_Device is abstract tagged limited
      record
         Block_Size : Positive;
         Input_File : File_Type;
         Output_File : File_Type;
      end record;

   type Mix_Card_Reader is new Mix_IO_Device with null record;

   function Create_Mix_Card_Reader return Mix_IO_Device'Class;

end Wossname;
```

I’m not 100% sure of the exact legality here, but I think this is "initializing in place":

```
package body Wossname is

   function Create_Mix_Card_Reader return Mix_IO_Device'Class is
   begin
      return Ret : Mix_Card_Reader do
         Ret.Block_Size := 16;
      end return;
   end Create_Mix_Card_Reader;

end Wossname;
```

and as you can see it compiles (and runs!) OK.

```
procedure Wossname.Test is
   Reader : Mix_IO_Device'Class := Create_Mix_Card_Reader;
begin
   begin
      Create (Reader.Output_File, Name => "wossname.out", Mode => Out_File);
   exception
      when Use_Error =>
         Open (Reader.Output_File, Name => "wossname.out", Mode => Out_File);
   end;
   Put (Reader.Output_File, "hi!");
   Close (Reader.Output_File);
end Wossname.Test;
```